# register user only with specific Host name

Tags: user-registration

Hii i want to that whenever any user register at my wordpress that just accepet email of specific host
for example if I want to accept only User register with username@gmail.com this email format
otherwise that show some error that you can only register with @gmail.com
so how to apply this condition and in which file
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the [User Domain Whitelist](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-domain-whitelist/) plugin is exactly what you want:

> The User Domain Whitelist/Blacklist plugin limits user registration to
>   only registrants with an email address from the domain white list
>   below OR prevents registrants with an email address from the domain
>   black list below from registering.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `register_post` hook to check if the email domain is in your whitelist and if not just add an error which will tell the user to use an email from your whitelist, something like:

```
function is_valid_email_domain($login, $email, $errors ){
    $valid_email_domains = array("gmail.com","yahoo.com");// whitelist
    $valid = false;
    foreach( $valid_email_domains as $d ){
        $d_length = strlen( $d );
        $current_email_domain = strtolower( substr( $email, -($d_length), $d_length));
        if( $current_email_domain == strtolower($d) ){
            $valid = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    // if invalid, return error
    if( $valid === false ){
        $errors->add('domain_whitelist_error',__( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: you can only register using gmail or yahoo emails' ));
    }
}

add_action('register_post', 'is_valid_email_domain',10,3 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is a validation question, not really a WordPress question.  You can add a JavaScript file that checks the value of the email field against `@gmail.com` on submission and either permits the form to submit or alerts the user to an error.

For example, this script would do what you want ...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#registerform').find(':submit').click(function(e) {
        if( ! isGmail( $('#user_email').val() ) ) {
            e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the form from submitting
            alert('You can only register with an @gmail.com email address!');
            return false;
        }
    });
});

function isGmail( address ) {
    return address.indexOf("@gmail.com", this.length - 10) !== -1;
}
```